# .htaccess clean url doesn`t work

Tags: php, .htaccess

here is my form

```
<form id="search" action="search.php" method="GET">
        Search : 
        <input type="text" id="searchKeyword" name="searchKeyword" placeholder="Search Keyword" />
        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="submit" value="search" /> 
    </form>
```

here is my search.php file :

```
<?php 
include("includes/connection.php"); 

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Search script by Mode2Code.Org</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<a href="index.php" id="back">Back!</a>

    <?php
    $keyword = $_GET['searchKeyword'];

    $keyword = htmlspecialchars($keyword);

    $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO searched (keyword) VALUES ('" . $keyword . "')";

    $insert = mysql_query($insertQuery);
    ?>
</body>
```

when I type in the keyword and press the search button, it makes the url like this:
website.com/search.php?searchKeyword=sometext

but I want my url to be like this
websute.com/search/sometext

here if my .htaccess

```
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

  RewriteRule ^profile/(\w+)$ ./search.php?searchKeyword=$1
  RewriteRule ^profile/(\w+)/$ ./search.php?searchKeyword=$1
```

I think there are no mistakes in my .htaccess but it is not working.
when I try to go to this url website.com/search/sometext It shows me 404 error.

can anyone help me ?

PS I am beginner in php :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below.

First change your form action as the default action is to post search.php either you will need to redirect it.

```
<form id="clean" method="get" action="./search/">
    <input type="search" name="searchKeyword" value="Text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Secondly, to redirect it well, you need to add some Javascript code, include jQuery in the page where the form is located if it's not included :

```
<script>
    $("#clean").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(location).attr('href',$(this).attr("action") + $("input[name$='searchKeyword']").val());
    });
</script>
```

Finally, change your .htaccess file a simpler version, also yours' redirecting page is profile.

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /stackoverflow/  : You may need to define the base too if it's in subdirectory
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/?$  search.php?searchKeyword=$1 [L]
```